# when crosscompiling with gcc (host=i386, target=x86_64) all binaries segfault

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I built a cross-tool-chain on `i386-pc-linux-gnu as --build and --host for --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu with binutils-2.27 and gcc-6.3.0.`

The tool-chain seems to work fine, producing binaries for x86_64.

However trying to boot into the newly compiled bash with `init=/tools/bin/bash` gives a segfault for bash, resulting in a kernel panic.

I compiled a static busybox, gdb and strace. The static binaries work and I am able to boot into busybox. Trying out the dynamically linked bash, it segfaults.

Here are the debug outputs of strace and gdb:

```
(gdb) r --help
Starting program: /tools/bin/bash --help

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7de91da in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=2, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffedf8, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffee10) at dl-init.c:72
#2  0x00007ffff7de92eb in call_init (env=0x7fffffffee10, argv=0x7fffffffedf8, argc=2, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:30
#3  _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe110, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffedf8, env=0x7fffffffee10) at dl-init.c:120
#4  0x00007ffff7ddac4a in _dl_start_user () from /tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fffffffef9d in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fffffffefad in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) 

execve("/tools/bin/bash", ["/tools/bin/bash"], [/* 4 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x15b5000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6a816a1000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffe1a856a90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/tls", 0x7ffe1a856a90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffe1a856a90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=207816, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6a8127d000
mprotect(0x7f6a81280000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6a8147f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f6a8147f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/tools/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\5\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15199320, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3901760, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f6a80ec4000
mprotect(0x7f6a81073000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f6a81273000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1af000) = 0x7f6a81273000
mmap(0x7f6a81279000, 14656, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6a81279000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f6a8169e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f6a8169e700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6a81273000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f6a8147f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x6df000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f6a816a3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xffffffffffffffff} ---
```

The segfault occurs before main() is called. There must be a problem with the dynamic loader of the cross-toolchain. I am kind of stuck at this point and would be grateful if someone has hints how to investigate further.

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably going to need to do some debugging (for example, run your program in a VM of the target environment using GDB or Valgrind) to determine which source line corresponds to the invalid access.  Make sure you link statically (against the correct target libraries), to rule out the dynamic linker and shared libraries as potential trouble sources.

Comment: Thanks I will try to get a cross gdb running. However there must be a problem with the toolchain since all compiled programs are affected.I know the description of the problem is quite generic unfortunately. But perhaps someone has seen something similar and is able to point me in the right direction. I suspect, the cross toolchain links to some wrong libs or includes the wrong headers at some point.